# React-Native/metadata.xml giving me a 403 forbidden

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, gradle

I have been running this react-native project on my android device and it has been working without any problems till yesterday.

Today when I run `react-native run-android` I am getting this following error:

```
> Task :app:preDebugBuild FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.facebook.react:react-native:0.20.+.
  Required by:
      project :app > project :react-native-charts-wrapper
   > Failed to list versions for com.facebook.react:react-native.
      > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo.spring.io/libs-release/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml.
         > Could not HEAD 'http://repo.spring.io/libs-release/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve com.facebook.react:react-native:0.12.+.
  Required by:
      project :app > project :react-native-i18n
   > Failed to list versions for com.facebook.react:react-native.
      > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo.spring.io/libs-release/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml.
         > Could not HEAD 'http://repo.spring.io/libs-release/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
```

Since it is a 403 I tried using a different Internet Connection and even a VPN , but it still is giving me the same error. Even my colleague is getting the same error.

This is the dependency on my build.gradle file : `implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"`

Are other people also facing this issue?

Wonder why this is happening and how can I solve this?Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it to work by changing `http` to `https` at:

```
maven {
            url "https://repo.spring.io/libs-release/"
            name 'Spring Libs'
        }
```

Weird though since it had no issue till a day ago. Lol